# Button open a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, button, android-fragments

I need to implement Fragment in my Android app that when pressed in a button open up. 
But I am not sure where to place the fragment in the XML.

The interaction is inside a listview, when you push the button in a item at the listview, the button will open the fragmemt. But should I have the implementation of the fragment in the xml of the listview row xml or in the main layout xml?

Comment: Fragments are not designed to be used in a `ListView`'s rows. Open it in the main layout which contains the `ListView`.

Comment: You are right. Fragment doesn't look like a proper solution did I found out. So my solution was to inflate a custom view when the button was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

First you should create a [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) which has at least a `LinearLayout`
And then you should create two [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html), one with the `ListView` and its items, one with what you want to do with.

In your `FragmentActivity` you can manage thoose two `Fragment` transactions.

Read [this Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) from Android Developer Site carefully. It has all information you need.

Comment: I found out that my thought about using listView to open a subview with fragments was not the best way to do it. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up concluding that it was a very bad idea to use fragment when opening a secondary view after pressed an item in the listView.

So my solution was to use and inflate a custom view at the moment the button was pressed inside the listview.